# Inverting an infinite sequence transformation

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, transformation

Consider a sequence $\{b_k\}$ define via:
$$
b_k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+k)!}{n!}a_n.
$$
I would like to invert this transform.  That is, I would like to know the coefficients $c_{nk}$ such that
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{nk} b_k
$$
(if they exists).

The following might be helpful.  I've found that if I make a small change
$$
b_k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+k)!}{n!}a_{n+k}
$$
then 
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{n!k!} b_{n+k}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Possibly useful: formally (i.e. without worrying about convergence) the Exponential Generating Function of $b_k$ is

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k \frac{t^k}{k!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n+k)!}{n!k!} a_n t^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (1-t)^{-n-1}$$